# Adding active class to slides javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help check my code to see what is wrong?
Trying to make my slides active one after the other.

```
function showSlide(n) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
    slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
    currentSlide = n;
    
  }

 // Pagination
  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;

  // Show the first slide
  showSlide(currentSlide);

  // Event listeners
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
```

Comment: Please add more code for debugging purpose

Comment: Please add the code to jsfiddle or codepen for better understanding.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a look at the [tour] to get a better understanding about how to add a [mre]!